# Python Console not allowing me to write a new line of code. PyCharm

Tags: python, api, console, pycharm, interactive-brokers

I am very new to Python, most of my code is done in R. In this code I am pulling data from Interactive Brokers API. The code is finished with 0 errors, however, the 3 green arrows in the console disappear and I am unable to write anything in the console or execute code in the script. Lastly, I hit the green debugging icon on the bottom left corner and now I am getting this "connecting to console" that does not go away.

I have an interpreter running on this project (python 3.7).

What I would like to see is the code to run, and after it is finished allow me to write code in the console and execute new code in the script as per usual. I have decided not to put in my Interactive brokers code as I believe it is redundant. If you would like to see it, I will upload it. Thank you.

[image]

Below is the interactive brokers code. The code comes directly from one of their sample scripts. I have decided to set the app.reqMktData on line 30 to True, True so I only receive a snapshot. I still receive the same problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        print("Tick Price. Ticker Id:", reqId, "tickType:", TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType), "Price:", price, end=" ")

    def tickSize(self, reqId, tickType, size):
        print("Tick Size. Ticker Id:", reqId, "tickType:", TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType), "Size:", size, end=" ")

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 4001, 0)

    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = "AAPL"
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    app.reqMarketDataType(4)
    app.reqMktData(1, contract, "", True, True, [])

    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I put the run.app above the reqmkt data, it just keeps spinning without returning anything. Thanks

Comment: Do you see the green arrow button on the left top of console window? press it and then u can write code again in console if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel said, this is a common problem that is a result of the threading from the API getting stuck open after your program returns. You won't be able to run your program and then continue to call the API in the console after. To solve the connecting to console issue, you need to disconnect from the API in your script by calling `app.disconnect()` before you return.

Also, consider adding these lines to your TestApp object:

```
thread = Thread(target=self.run)
thread.start()

setattr(self, "_thread", thread)
```

This will start the thread for you, and you no longer need to call `app.run()`

You will need to import the Thread class from the Threading module - `from Threading import Thread`

This blog can help you with the implementation of the other classes and using queues to receive the callbacks from the API. https://qoppac.blogspot.com/2017/03/interactive-brokers-native-python-api.html

Comment: Thanks Jared, this worked great!! One thing I found is ib_insync. The code is alot easier to follow. Is there any reason why I should not use this? I have seen mixed reviews on using IB native python vs wrapping it in ib_insync

Comment: I'm not sure, I have never used ib_insync because I don't need to have real-time streaming for my code. If you will need that, it would be easier to use the ib_insync instead of trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're seeing here is representative of the two-thread system that IB uses for its API. ([link](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/connection.html#ereader))

As the app is run, these threads run in infinite loops to gather and process data.

From what I can see in your image, you only returned one tick from reqmktdata() before 'exiting with code 0.' In my own, albeit C#, implementation of reqmktdata I am returning a consistent stream of data. (For AAPL, it would be several ticks per second and several tick types.)

There is a good chance that what you're seeing is some locking caused by the deliberate, but non-terminating infinite loop of these two threads.

Suggestions:

- Try putting app.run() ahead of your reqmktdata() call. (This is a longshot, as I'm not familiar with IB's Python implementation)
- It would be worthwhile stepping through your code line by line to see where exactly it decides to exit. From my own experience, this code should not exit until you decide to stop it. (ie: should be printing many lines of output)

Comment: Hey Daniel, I uploaded the code and tried your suggestions, still no luck!! Your theory makes perfect sense, so i set the  statement to true, true to only recieve a snaphsot. Still, no luck.

Comment: In the sample code from API Version 9.74.01, I see these lines. tc = TestClient(None) tc.reqMktData(1101, ContractSamples.USStockAtSmart(), "", False, None). They imply that there is an IBClient that is necessary to request quotes. The sample code is notoriously complex. The only way I was able to gain an understanding of how the C# API works was to use the Sample solution in its entirety and adapt it accordingly - every attempt to start from scratch was met with severe frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest restarting PyCharm to get rid of those "Connecting to console" tasks. My guess is that it's failing because the console is dead.

Then use the action (Ctrl+Shift+A or Ctrl+3 to find action) "Run file in Console".